# Set & load environment variables in a phoenix app

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm new to a Phoenix framework and am looking for a way to set environment variables in the app. One way I found is [here](https://medium.com/@kkomaz/phoenix-setting-up-env-variables-6557eb1370ee).

However, I don't like this way since I need to type `source .env` whenever I restart the app.

I tried setting the ENV variables in `prod.secret.exs` like below:

```
config :oauth,
  GITHUB_CLIENT_ID: "(CLIENT ID)",
  GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET: "(SECRET)"
```

And I tried retrieving ENV variables in a following way:

```
 config :ueberauth, Ueberauth.Strategy.Github.OAuth,
   client_id: System.get_env("GITHUB_CLIENT_ID"),
   client_secret: System.get_env("GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET")
```

However, when I run the server using `mix phoenix.server`, it gives me an error like below and I'm not sure what it really means:

```
You have configured application :oauth in your configuration
file, but the application is not available.

This usually means one of:

1. You have not added the application as a dependency in a mix.exs file.

2. You are configuring an application that does not really exist.

Please ensure :oauth exists or remove the configuration.
```

I'm looking for a way to save ENV variables in the project itself in a hidden file so it can be retrieved anytime I want. Can someone tell me what's the right way of saving ENV variables and retrieving them in a Phoenix app?

Comment: `config :oauth, GITHUB_CLIENT_ID: "(CLIENT ID)"` will _not_ set ENV variables. Maybe you want https://github.com/avdi/dotenv_elixir.

Comment: @Dogbert, I read about it, but I didn't feel like it wasn't an Elixir way of setting the ENV variables. I was looking for more of a native(?) way.

Comment: Are you running this as part of a linux service like upstart or sytemd? Because if you are why care how you get secret values into your app. Just pick a solution and move on to coding.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found another example

1.- Create a file `.env` in you main folder

2.- Add the env variables in the `.env` file

```
# Example:
# MyApp/.env file
export GITHUB_CLIENT_ID="testID"
export GITHUB_SECRET_CLIENT_ID="testSecretID"
```

3.- Run `source .env` and every time it is modified, execute the command again, maybe in reboot too

4.- What is really **important** - don't forget to add your secret files to `MyApp/.gitignore`

```
# add this at the end
/.env
```

5.- Run phoenix server `mix phx.server` or `mix phoenix.server`

**You can test it with**

```
iex -S mix phoenix.server

iex> System.get_env("GITHUB_CLIENT_ID")
"testID"
```

**Links of help:**

[Environment variable error](https://elixirforum.com/t/environment-variable-error/28119/4)
[Documentation of config](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Config.html)

Comment: This works well enough for me and keeps system configuration out of elixir code. Easy enough to define separate `.env` files containing the various secrets.Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are two main glitches with what you are trying to do:

First of all, you are trying to instruct `mix` to configure `oauth` OTP application, while what you need is to configure your own one:

```
config :my_app, :oauth,
  github_client_id: "(CLIENT ID)",
  github_client_secret: "(SECRET)"
```

Now in your main config you might do:

```
config :ueberauth, Ueberauth.Strategy.Github.OAuth,
   client_id: Application.get_env(:my_app, :oauth)[:github_client_id],
   client_secret: Application.get_env(:my_app, :oauth)[:github_client_secret]
```

The second glitch is that `GITHUB_CLIENT_ID` is an atom, and you are trying to access it lately as a string. In general, one should not use atom names starting with an uppercase since they kinda reserved for modules names.

On the other hand, you might still use `System.get_env/2` (with your `config.ex`,) assuming the values were previously *put* there in environment:

**`prod.secret.exs`** (as it is still plain Elixir)

```
System.put_env("GITHUB_CLIENT_ID", "(CLIENT ID)")
System.put_env("GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET", "(CLIENT SECRET)")
```

Comment: I tried both ways and it seems like ENV variables are not being set :/ When I run `Application.get_env(:my_app, :oauth)[:github_client_id]` and `System.get_env("GITHUB_CLIENT_ID")` following your ways, I still get nil in `iex -S mix phoenix.server`.

Comment: 1) in the system shell environment, 2) `prod.secret.exs` is good enough, 3) No idea, I never did that with `System.put_env`, I would suggest it’s because the system environment is loaded when `mix` or even erlang VM starts, or like.

Comment: `Application.get_env(:my_app, :oauth)[:github_client_id]` can not be `nil`. `System.get_env` can and probably is, because of race condition / order of environment load.

Comment: Make sure you `import_config "prod.secret.exs"` from `config/prod.ex` **before** requesting `Application.get_env`.

Comment: I'm still getting nil for `Application.get_env` request and I'm following `config :my_app, :oauth` for now. Do you think I'm getting `nil` because I am requesting `Application.get_env` in `config.exs` than `prod.exs`?

Comment: `config.exs` reads `prod.exs` that in turn reads `prod.secret.exs` in production environment only. Also, the order or inclusion matters. Just make the `prod.secret.exs` file is loaded in the first place.

Comment: (1) To ensure that the `prod.secret.exs` is loaded in the first place, I put `import_config "prod.secret.exs"` on top of `config.exs`, but it still returns nil for `Application.get_env`. I'm not 100% sure how to make sure it is loaded before `Application.get_env` gets called.
(2) I think another issue is that I am trying to check the ENV variables in PRODUCTION mode when my app is running on dev mode at the moment. I tried setting Env variables in `dev.secret.exs` but still no luck.

Comment: However remember that these variables will be set during compilation, not during runtime, so as OP says, you will need to update them on launch.

Answer (score 2):

When starting phoenix and using environment variables (`System.get_env("GITHUB_CLIENT_ID")`)you'll need to do something like this to pass in variables:

`GITHUB_CLIENT_ID=12345 GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET=67890 mix phoenix.server`

Comment: This is the way explicitly mentioned in the first sentence of the OP as _known but not wanted_.